# How to set the text to the addition of the selected cells

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, jtextarea

I have a textArea, a JTable and an "Add" button

When I select a cell, the value should appear on the textarea. When i press add and then select another cell, the addition of the selected cells must appear on the textarea.

I know the following is wrong, what am I missing?

Should I do something to the text area so that a variable holds the last value shown in the textarea and then pass it to the addition's action listener? If so, how to do it?

Additional question :- Why can't an actionlistener be applied to a textarea or a table?

```
addition.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        ClickAdd();
     }
});

private void ClickAdd(){
    val = GetSelectedValue();
    int num1=Integer.parseInt(val);
    visualize.setText("Select a number to add to " + num1);
    val=GetSelectedValue();
    int num2=Integer.parseInt(val);
    int total=num1+num2;
    visualize.setText(String.valueOf(total));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all method names ("ClickAdd") should NOT start with an upper case character. Read the Java API and show me a single method that does start with an upper case character. Learn by example and don't make up your own conventions.

Don't use the setText(...) method.

Instead use:

```
visualize.adppend(..);
```

> Why can't an actionlistener be applied to a textarea or a table?

Because there is no API for that and it doesn't make sense. You have other listeners that you can use.